# How to change the text color of a MS teams Message Card

Tags: webhooks, microsoft-teams

I am using AWS Lambda with a webhook to post to a Teams Channel. How do I change the text color in the card?

AFAIK, Adaptive Cards are not an option for webhooks yet. I have tried using the Message Card playground but there is not an option for the legacy Message Card, and other sites I've looked at don't have a text color option.

I'd like to change the color of the title, but the following has not worked.

Code I've tried:

````
data = {
            "@context": "https://schema.org/extensions",
            "@type": "MessageCard",
            "themeColor": "0072C6",
            "color": "FF0000",
            "title": self.title + " Severity: " + str(self.severity),
            "text": self.findings + "\n Account: "+self.account+" \nTags: " + json.dumps(self.tags)} ```
````

Comment: As of now we don't support text color style for messages card but you can use [Text Formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/message-card-reference#text-formatting) for messages card.

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 3):

It is possible by HTML formatting eg. in title or text. It works for me

```
<strong style="color:blue;"> My title </strong>
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Trinetra-MSFT mentioned, there is not an option to change text color in MS Message Cards.

Comment: thanks for this .was searching for this for a while.
was trying to send a card with changed text color when a build fails

Answer (score 0):

It is possible! Use simple html formatting.

```
json_data = {
    "@type": "MessageCard",
    "themeColor": "0bd700",
    "summary": "Successful Bamboo Deployment",
    "sections": 
    [{
        "activityTitle": '<h1 style="color:green;"> Successful Deployment </h1>',
    }]
}
```

[Click here to see what it does](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Puz6h.png)

Comment: Does this add anything to Sebastian Zalewski's 2020 answer?